# Could dark matter be explained by the fact of empty space expanding much faster than space inside galaxies?

Tags: dark-matter

We know the expansion of the universe is accelerating and mass slows time.
So pockets of empty space experienced more time since the big bang.
That mean the current expansion rate of empty space is much faster and had more time to expand.
Could dark matter be the outside pressure of empty space on the galaxy?
Does the current model takes into account this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

No.
We observe the effects of dark matter within galaxies and across galaxy clusters, as well as across the entire universe. So it is by no means just about the rotation curves of galaxies, and your idea can not explain the data.
Yes, current models of structure formation properly take this effect into account - by ignoring it, since indeed it is negligible anyway.